# reshape the data in r using pivot_longer

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to reshape the following data in r using the command pivot_longer.

Original data:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  famid named  incd namem  incm
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 Bill  30000 Bess  15000
2     2 Art   22000 Amy   18000
3     3 Paul  25000 Pat   50000
```

and what I want to get:

```
    ## # A tibble: 6 x 4
    ##   famid Parent Name  Income
    ##   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <int>
    ## 1     1 dad    Bill   30000
    ## 2     1 mom    Bess   15000
    ## 3     2 dad    Art    22000
    ## 4     2 mom    Amy    18000
    ## 5     3 dad    Paul   25000
    ## 6     3 mom    Pat    50000
```

The code I tried is:

```
dadmom %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = named|namem,
    names_to = "parent",
    names_pattern = "name(.)",
    values_to = "name"
  )
```

and I got:

```
famid incd  incm parent name
1   30000   15000   d   Bill
1   30000   15000   m   Bess
2   22000   18000   d   Art
2   22000   18000   m   Amy
3   25000   50000   d   Paul
3   25000   50000   m   Pat
```

**Question:** how do I drop the duplicating income in using pivote_longer and reshape the data in one pipe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
dadmom %>%
 pivot_longer(
   cols = matches("^(name|inc)"),
   names_to = c(".value", "mom_or_dad"),
   names_pattern = "(name|inc)(.)"
 )
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   famid mom_or_dad name    inc
#   <int> <chr>      <chr> <int>
# 1     1 d          Bill  30000
# 2     1 m          Bess  15000
# 3     2 d          Art   22000
# 4     2 m          Amy   18000
# 5     3 d          Paul  25000
# 6     3 m          Pat   50000
```